# Questions about sentinels? Beginner Java Programming

Tags: java, sentinel

I have this program that uses user input to find sum of number entered, aswell as the smallest numbers and how many integers have been entered by the users.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

int numOfints = 0;
int numberin;
int sum = 0;
int small;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter the numbers. <-999 to stop>: ");
System.out.print("Please enter the first number: ");
numberin = input.nextInt();
small = numberin;

while(numberin!=-999)
{

numOfints++; 
sum+=numberin;

}
if (numberin >0)
{

System.out.println("Total number of numbers inputted was" +numOfints);
System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + sum);
System.out.println("The smallest number in the set is" + small);

}
else

System.out.println("The number set is empty, therefore no calculations can be performed.");

}

}

{
```

However when I run the program the only thing that appears is

```
c:\jwork>java lab7a
Please enter the numbers; <-999 to stop>: Please enter the first number: 1
_
```

and it does not allow for anymore inputs from the user. Why won't the program continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any methods of getting input from the user within your `while` loop.